# Request Failed with status 404, On Click on Delete button, Unable to delete the Product using React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am facing this error "DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/undefined 404 (Not Found)". On click on Delete button ,I need to delete the Product, Here I am passing "ProductID" as Dynamically to that URL.Can anyone help me in this, What's Wrong I am doing here..Please help me Thanks in Advance

Here is the Redux Action

```
export const deleteallprodcuts = (productId:string) =>{

    return async (dispatch:any) => {
        try {
           
            let dataURL : string = `http://localhost:3000/users/${productId}`;
            let response = await axios.delete(dataURL);
            dispatch({type:DELETE_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS , payload : response.data});
            // get the latest products info
            dispatch(fetchallproducts());
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Delete Component

```
interface IState {
    products : IProduct[]
}

 const ProductAdmin = () => {
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    let getalldatafromserver :allReducer.Iproducts = useSelector((state : {fetchalldata:allReducer.Iproducts})=>{
        return state.fetchalldata;
  })
  
     useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(getalldatafromserver.products);
          dispatch(allActions.fetchallproducts())
     }, [])

     let deleteProduct = (productId : string) => {
        dispatch(allActions.deleteallprodcuts(productId));
     };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
     
                    <section className="mt-3">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <p className="h3 text-success">Product Admin</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex impedit, incidunt ipsum nulla sapiente sint suscipit? A animi, error et fuga ipsum minus, nam officia praesentium quisquam, recusandae soluta voluptate?</p>
                                    <Link to="/products/create" className="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create Product</Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section className="mt-3">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <table className="table table-hover text-center table-striped">
                                        <thead className="bg-dark text-success">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>SNO</th>
                                            <th>Product</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>Qty</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        {
                                            getalldatafromserver.products.length > 0 &&
                                            getalldatafromserver.products.map(product => {
                                                return (
                                                    <tr key={product._id}>
                                                        <td>{product._id?.substr(product._id.length - 5)}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <img src={product.image} alt="" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>{product.name}</td>
                                                        <td>&#8377; {product.price}</td>
                                                        <td>{product.qty} Kgs</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Update</Link>
                                                            <button onClick={deleteProduct.bind(this, product._id as string)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        }
                                        {
                                            // for empty data
                                            getalldatafromserver.products.length === 0 &&
                                            <tr>
                                                <td className="text-success" colSpan={6}>NO Records Found in Database</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </React.Fragment>
        
  
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Problem
<button onClick={deleteProduct.bind(this, product._id as string)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete

We need to get the data from server, product._id is not available there...